# Generate and download JSON file return always an html file

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I generate a JSON file with PHP and via the headers I download it as soon as the generation of the file is finished. When I run the code below, I look in my "downloads" folder and the extension of the downloaded file is not ".json" but ".json.html".

How to make the extension of the file remain ".json"?

Here is my code:

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket)
{
    $data['tickets'][] = [
        'tickets_id' => $ticket->ticket_id,
        'name' => strtolower($ticket->name),
        'email' => strtolower($ticket->email),
        'status' => $ticket->status
    ];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=db.json');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Downloaded file is => db.json.html **not** db.json

Edit : FULL CODE BELOW

```
public function ticketsExportJSON($id)
{
    $tickets = Ticket::where('event_id', $id)->with('event')->get();

    $data = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach($tickets as $ticket)
    {
        $i++;
        if($i == 1)
        {
            $data = [
                'event' => $ticket->event->title,
                'date' => $ticket->event->event_date
            ];
        }
        else
        {
            $data['tickets'][] = [
                'tickets_id' => $ticket->ticket_id,
                'name' => strtolower($ticket->name),
                'email' => strtolower($ticket->email),
                'status' => $ticket->status
            ];
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=db.json');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

With a route : /download/json to call ticketsExportJSON function.

Comment: is there anything else in your php file?

Comment: Nothing else ...

Comment: how do you download it?

Comment: I call a url : mywebsite.com/download/json and the file is downloaded with headers (content-disposition : attachement; filename=db.json)

Comment: If you open the db.json.html, is the right data there?

Comment: Yes the content of the file is OK. I just need to conserve the original extension ".json"

Comment: my guess is, that Laravel sends some headers (ContentType?) before yours.

Comment: I think Laravel is doing this.  You need to return a proper repsonse object.  Docs are here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads

Comment: @WillardSolutions : nope, it change nothing => Safari rename the file with another extension. The extension .json is good with chrome and firefox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `exit();` in the end of your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.

Comment: No, Safari rename the Json file by default. I don't kwnow why. The code work fine with Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `streamDownload()` method (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#file-download), by passing `[ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ]` as third argument.